# PUT Elasticsearch Ingest Pipeline by default

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, kibana, filebeat

We currently use Elasticsearch for storage of Spring Boot App logs that are sent by Filebeat and use Kibana to visualise this.

Our entire architecture is dockerized inside a docker-compose file. Currently, our when we start the stack, we have to wait for Elasticsearch to start, then PUT our Ingest Pipeline, then restart Filebeat, and **only then** do our logs show up properly ingested in Kibana.

I'm quite new to this, but I was wondering if there is no way to have Elasticsearch save ingest pipelines so that you do not have to load them every single time? I read about mounting volumes or running custom scripts to wait for ES and PUT when ready, but all of this seems very cumbersome for a use case that to me seems like the default?

Answer (score 1):

We used a similar approach to ozlevka, by running a script during the build process of our custom Elasticsearch image.

This is our script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# This script sets up the Elasticsearch docker instance with the correct pipelines and templates

baseUrl='localhost:9200'
contentType='Content-Type:application/json'

# filebeat
ingestUrl=$baseUrl'/_ingest/pipeline/our-pipeline?pretty'
payload='/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/our-pipeline.json'

/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p /tmp/pid > /dev/null & 
# wait until Elasticsearch is up
# you can get logs if you change /dev/null to /dev/stderr
while [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' -XPUT $ingestUrl -H$contentType -d@$payload)" != "200" ]]; do
    echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch to start and posting pipeline..."
    sleep 5
done

kill -SIGTERM $(cat /tmp/pid) 
rm /tmp/pid
echo -e "\n\n\nCompleted Elasticsearch Setup, refer to logs for details"
```

Comment: Gonig through the same issue. Can you plesae share the `Dockerfile` for your custom elasticsearch image. I want to know how this bash script is being executed inside it during the build. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the startscript into filebeat container.

The script will ping elasticsearch be ready, after this create pipeline and start filebeat.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e

START_FILE=/tmp/.es_start_file
http () {
    local path="${1}"
    curl -XGET -s -k --fail http://${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:{$ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}${path}
}

pipeline() {
    curl -XPUT -s -k --fail http://${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:{$ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}/_ingest/pipeline/$PIPELINE_NAME -d @pipeline.json
}

while true; do
    if [ -f "${START_FILE}" ]; then
        pipeline
        /usr/bin/filebeat -c filebeat.yaml &
        exit 0    
    else
        echo 'Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become green'
        if http "/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s" ; then
            touch ${START_FILE}
        fi    
    fi
done
```

This method will be good for docker-compose and docker swarm. For k8s preferable create readiness probe.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Indeed we ended up doing something similar: During the build process of our Elasticsearch custom image we create the pipeline, thus removing the need to do it on startup of the container. I posted it above.